# Gunicorn SSL exception

Tags: ssl, gunicorn

I am runninug Gunicorn 19.9.0 and when accessing the webpage I receive an exception. This causes the browser the gunicorn to freeze for a few minutes until it is able to start serving again.

These are my pip packages and I am running python 2.7

```
adal==1.0.2
alabaster==0.7.11
alembic==0.8.10
amqp==2.3.2
analytics-python==1.2.9
apache-airflow==1.10.0
asn1crypto==0.24.0
atlasclient==0.1.2
awscli==1.16.1
azure-common==1.1.14
azure-datalake-store==0.0.19
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-store==0.4.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-resource==1.2.2
azure-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-storage==0.36.0
Babel==2.6.0
backports-abc==0.5
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
bcrypt==3.1.4
billiard==3.5.0.4
bleach==2.1.2
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.8.5
botocore==1.11.1
cachetools==2.1.0
cassandra-driver==3.15.0
celery==4.2.1
certifi==2018.8.24
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
cloudant==0.5.10
colorama==0.3.9
configparser==3.5.0
cookies==2.2.1
croniter==0.3.25
cryptography==2.3.1
cx-Oracle==6.4.1
datadog==0.22.0
decorator==4.3.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
dicttoxml==1.7.4
dill==0.2.8.2
docker==3.5.0
docker-pycreds==0.3.0
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.14
elasticsearch==5.5.3
elasticsearch-dsl==5.4.0
entrypoints==0.2.3
enum34==1.1.6
fastavro==0.9.6
Flask==0.12.4
Flask-Admin==1.4.1
Flask-AppBuilder==1.11.1
Flask-Babel==0.11.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Caching==1.3.3
Flask-Login==0.2.11
Flask-OpenID==1.2.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
flask-swagger==0.2.13
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
flower==0.9.2
freezegun==0.3.10
funcsigs==1.0.0
future==0.16.0
future-fstrings==0.4.4
futures==3.2.0
gitdb2==2.0.4
GitPython==2.1.11
google-api-core==1.3.0
google-api-python-client==1.7.4
google-auth==1.5.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.2.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.5.0
google-cloud-container==0.1.1
google-cloud-core==0.28.1
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
grpcio==1.14.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
hdfs==2.1.0
hmsclient==0.1.1
html5lib==1.0.1
httplib2==0.11.3
idna==2.7
ijson==2.3
imagesize==1.1.0
inflection==0.3.1
ipaddress==1.0.22
iso8601==0.1.12
isodate==0.6.0
itsdangerous==0.24
JayDeBeApi==1.1.1
Jinja2==2.8.1
jira==2.0.0
jmespath==0.9.3
JPype1==0.6.3
keyring==13.2.1
kombu==4.2.1
kubernetes==7.0.0
ldap3==2.5.1
lockfile==0.12.2
lxml==3.8.0
Mako==1.0.7
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==1.0
mock==2.0.0
mongomock==3.11.1
monotonic==1.5
moto==1.1.19
msrest==0.4.29
msrestazure==0.4.34
multi-key-dict==2.0.3
mysqlclient==1.3.13
ndg-httpsclient==0.5.1
nose==1.3.7
nose-ignore-docstring==0.2
nose-timer==0.7.3
ntlm-auth==1.2.0
numpy==1.15.1
oauthlib==2.1.0
ordereddict==1.1
packaging==17.1
pandas==0.23.4
pandas-gbq==0.6.1
parameterized==0.6.1
paramiko==2.4.1
pathlib2==2.3.2
pbr==4.2.0
pendulum==1.4.4
pinotdb==0.1.1
protobuf==3.6.1
psutil==4.4.2
psycopg2==2.7.5
psycopg2-binary==2.7.5
pyaml==17.12.1
pyasn1==0.4.4
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
pycparser==2.18
pycryptodomex==3.6.6
pydruid==0.4.5
Pygments==2.2.0
PyHive==0.6.0
PyJWT==1.6.4
pykerberos==1.2.1
pymongo==3.7.1
pymssql==2.1.4
PyNaCl==1.2.1
pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
pysftp==0.2.9
PySmbClient==0.1.5
python-daemon==2.1.2
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-editor==1.0.3
python-http-client==3.1.0
python-jenkins==1.2.1
python-nvd3==0.15.0
python-openid==2.2.5
python-slugify==1.2.5
pytz==2015.7
pytzdata==2018.5
pywinrm==0.3.0
PyYAML==3.13
qds-sdk==1.9.9
redis==2.10.6
rednose==1.3.0
requests==2.19.1
requests-futures==0.9.4
requests-kerberos==0.12.0
requests-mock==1.5.2
requests-ntlm==1.1.0
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
rsa==3.4.2
ruamel.ordereddict==0.4.13
ruamel.yaml==0.15.64
s3transfer==0.1.13
sasl==0.2.1
scandir==1.9.0
SecretStorage==2.3.1
sendgrid==5.6.0
sentinels==1.0.0
setproctitle==1.1.10
simplejson==3.16.0
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.11.0
slackclient==1.2.1
smmap2==2.0.4
snakebite==2.11.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
snowflake-connector-python==1.6.8
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.1.2
Sphinx==1.7.8
sphinx-argparse==0.2.2
Sphinx-PyPI-upload==0.2.1
sphinx-rtd-theme==0.4.1
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.1.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.18
tabulate==0.7.7
tenacity==4.8.0
termstyle==0.1.11
text-unidecode==1.2
thrift==0.11.0
thrift-sasl==0.3.0
tokenize-rt==2.0.1
tornado==5.1
typing==3.6.6
tzlocal==1.5.1
unicodecsv==0.14.1
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.23
vertica-python==0.7.4
vine==1.1.4
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==0.51.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.2.1
xmltodict==0.11.0
zdesk==2.7.1
zope.deprecation==4.3.0
```

This is the stacktrace. I see references to ssl and gunicorn.

```
[2018-09-06 22:14:35 +0000] [54] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:498)
[2018-09-06 22:14:35 +0000] [498] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 498)
[2018-09-06 22:14:35 +0000] [823] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 823
[2018-09-06 22:14:35,770] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2018-09-06 22:14:36,079] {models.py:258} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
[2018-09-06 22:14:36 +0000] [823] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
    req = six.next(parser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/parser.py", line 41, in __next__
    self.mesg = self.mesg_class(self.cfg, self.unreader, self.req_count)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 181, in __init__
    super(Request, self).__init__(cfg, unreader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 54, in __init__
    unused = self.parse(self.unreader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 193, in parse
    self.get_data(unreader, buf, stop=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 184, in get_data
    data = unreader.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 38, in read
    d = self.chunk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 65, in chunk
    return self.sock.recv(self.mxchunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 766, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 653, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
error: [Errno 0] Error
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not just a network timeout? Does it always fail? Did you try another client? And same client with another server? When did the problem start and what did you just before?

Comment: Hi @PatrickMevzek . I'm certain it's not a network timeout. When I'm in the docker container that is hosting gunicorn, my attempts to curl the https interface also freezes for a minute. I am doing a proof of concept of Airflow 10, so I haven't seen this issue before.

Comment: Your connection is dying during the TLS handshake.  The "Errno 0" issue has been addressed as **[discussed here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1776)**.